# How to update between beta releases on (K)Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: kubuntu, beta

so I'm on the previous Beta build of Kubuntu 23.04, but I don't know how I can update to today's build. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

I tried `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` and `sudo do-release-upgrade` already, but it says that there're no releases available, even though there has been a newer iso of 23.04. Beta today. Also, `sudo apt dist-upgrade` doesn't find anything either.

Is it not possible to upgrade to today's build via Konsole somehow?

Would be great if somebody had an idea.

Best wishes

Comment: Beta / development releases are not supported here (yet)

Comment: Oh, okay I didn't know. Sorry for posting then

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *lunar* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 13 April 2023, and isn't on-topic here until release on 20 April 2023.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/lunar-lobster-release-schedule/27284  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *lunar* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though beta-releases are not supported on AU:

In terminal run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

or run the Software Updater app.

Both methods will add the latest updates to the beta.

Comment: Do note you'll find `apt upgrade` may not be enough and need to use `apt full-upgrade`.   If you read `man apt` on your *lunar* system (*I'm using it too*) you'll read "*full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole.*" ... ie. `apt upgrade` may leave some upgrades uninstallable which is intentional (*giving you control on when you action those deletes*).   (`apt full-upgrade` tends to be needed more during *development* (*alpha* & *beta*) than released products!)

Comment: Hey there @guiverc, thank you very much for that explanation! As you're on lunar lobster as well maybe you can answer another beta related question: Are you able to use all plasma effects? For me it seems I can enable them, but they just don't work, i.e. the effects don't trigger and instead I have zero effects. I wonder if it has to do with the beta or if I messed up something at some point?

Comment: Just as an UPDATE: I found my biggest underlying problem, which was that somehow when I installed 23.04 it wiped/deleted/w/e my proprietary nvidia drivers. Always when I navigated to system settings --> Driver management all proprietary drivers were greyed out, claiming only a manual driver was installed. I thought this might just be normal on a beta and didn't boggle my mind too much. Now I've installed nvidia 530 proprietary drivers via Muon Package manager, leaving me with a MUCH better installation. Games are working again, plasma effects are back working etc. Everything is just smoother